# Quick technical python question that I'm stuck on (new to python)

Tags: python

Current tests fail because function returns one value then breaks

Expected:

```
Ottawa: 5
Toronto: 12
```

Mine:

```
Toronto: 12
```

What am I missing here?

I'm submitting this on a time controlled test (coming from javascript and c#) and I can't figure out exactly how it wants me to return them both as a string.

```
def get_rainfall():

rainfall = {}
while True:
    cityn = input()
    if not cityn:
        for city, rain in rainfall.items():

            print(f'{city}: {rain}')
            return str(f'{city}: {rain}')
        # couldnt figure out how to send entire array as string instead of just one

        break
    
    rain = input();
    rainfall[cityn] = rainfall.get(cityn, 0) + int(rain);

#######    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')


result = get_rainfall()

fptr.write(result + '\n')

fptr.close()
```

removing

```
return str(f'{city}: {rain}')
```

lets my print function to return the expected result
otherwise test cases fail

EDIT :
I was able to return it with a few changes

```
    while True:
    cityn = input()
    if not cityn:
        rainList = ""
        for city, rain in rainfall.items():
            a = (f'{city}: {rain} ')
            rainList += a;
            
        return rainList
        break
    
    rain = input();
    rainfall[cityn] = rainfall.get(cityn, 0) + int(rain);
```

Expected:

```
 Ottawa: 5
 Toronto: 12
```

Mine:

```
 Ottawa: 5 Toronto: 12
```

So test cases failed. Not really sure but I'll leave this here just in case anybody ever wants to see

Comment: `return` works the same as it does in Javascript, and afaik, C# as well. Once you return from a function, you exit it. How would you do this in Javascript?

Comment: Can you not just create an empty string beforehand and then concatenate each city's info to the string, then return that after the loop is done? What's different about this compared to how you'd do it in JavaScript or C#?

Comment: Thats what I figured but for some reason it is only returning a single item before exiting

Comment: @AngelEscobedo *because you are returning on the first iteration of the loop*. This is exactly the same as it would work in JS, C#. In your loop, you have to build up your result.

Comment: Because you return in the loop. Make a list ls before the loop,  call ls.append(foo) in the loop, then return ls.

Comment: As an aside, `return str(f'{city}: {rain}')` could just have been `return f'{city}: {rain}'` since `f'{city}: {rain}'` is a string already. Also, this is HackerRank, isn't it? I really hate their archaic way of making you dump some string representation to some file.